# In TFS 2015, for a vNext build, can you read the build logs in a build step?

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I can't give a lot of background, but the question is as follows:

In TFS 2015.2, is there a way to access the build logs of a vNext build while the build is happening or afterwards as another build step, using a Powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to read the build logs while the vNext build is running. However, you can try to get the logs of the executed step by using [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#logs) in a powershell script.

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/builds/391/logs?api-version=2.0
```

Comment: Actually I think it's a bug in update 2. In the VSO (Visual Studio Online) which is suppose to use the latest build I managed to see the log while the build step was running.

Comment: Which method are you using in VSTS ? Ps: We have changed the name from VSO to VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought he was talking about the ability to see (actually see) the logs on the UI live while running. I had that problem when using update 2.1.